# Code for printing list in React

Tags: react.js, jsx

Below is an implementation of a React app printing list. Are there any areas of improvement/suggestions in below code base

```
  class ListElement extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
       return <li onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.index)}>{this.props.item.text}</li>;
   }
}

class ListComponent extends React.Component {

       handleClick(index) {
           this.props.onClick(index);
       }

       render() {
           const listDetails = this.props.listDetails;
           let height,width;
           if (listDetails.hasOwnProperty("size")) {
               height = listDetails.size.height;
               width = listDetails.size.width;
           }
           return (
               <ul style={{  height: height, width }}>
                   {this.props.items.map((item, i) => <ListElement item={item} key={i} index={i} handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>)}
               </ul>
           );
       }
    }

    ListComponent.propTypes = {
       items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
           text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
       })).isRequired,
       listDetails: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use function syntax/[memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) when possible
- Use destructuring
- Use object literal shorthand
- Define defaults for `width` and `height`
- `handleClick` is just `onClick` renamed
- Use tooling for formatting your code (eslint, prettier)
- Prefer ternary over if (not always true)
- Have a well defined API for your components (ListElement needs text, not the entire item, and doesn't really need index)

```js
const ListElement = React.Memo(({ handleClick, label }) => (
  <li onClick={handleClick()}>{label}</li>
));

const ListComponent = React.Memo(
  ({
    items,
    listDetails: {
      size: { height, width }
    },
    onClick
  }) => (
    <ul style={{ height, width }}>
      {items.map(({ text }, i) => (
        <ListElement label={text} key={i} handleClick={() => onClick(i)} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
);

ListComponent.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  ).isRequired,
  listDetails: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

// Not quite sure I'm setting defaultProps correctly here, but you get the idea
ListComponent.defaultProps = {
  listDetails: { size: { height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT, width: DEFAULT_WIDTH } }
};
```

You can also update `propTypes` with the shape of `listDetails` or change so that `ListComponent` takes `size` as an attribute instead, depending on what makes sense in your scenario.